# Why bad_alloc() exception thrown in case of size_t

Tags: c++, windows, exception

I am working on the below piece of code and when I'm executing this code, I'm getting a `std::bad_alloc` exception:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
 FILE * pFile;

 size_t state;
 pFile = fopen("C:\\shared.tmp", "rb");
 if (pFile != NULL)
 {
    size_t rt = fread(&state, sizeof(int), 1, pFile);
    char *string = NULL;
    string= new char[state + 1];
    fclose(pFile);
 }
 return 0;
}
```

This below line causing exception to be thrown:

```
string = new char[state + 1];
```

Why this is happening and how can I fix this?

Comment: May you print state  before allocation and post the result ?

Comment: A debugger, a breakpoint, and a watch window will probably tell you just how big the thing is you're trying to allocate. My crystal ball tells me you're size is stored in a form not in concert with a `size_t`, but you're treating it as one anyway, particularly since you're reading the size of an `int`, and storing in a `size_t, which on your platform are probably 32bit and 64bit respectively. Ouch.

Comment: I would also be worried about endianness, since this code reads directly into the internal representation of the integral type rather than constructing it out of bytes. The OP may think he's reading an integer with value `0x000000FF`, but he may be getting `0xFF0000000` instead!

Comment: @HumamHelfawi - Please see the print result before allocation  - "3435973638"

Comment: Is there any impact on my code if i initialized size_t state =0 before using it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're passing the address of an uninitialized 64-bit (8 bytes, on modern 64-bit systems) variable, `state`, and tell `fread` to read `sizeof(int)` (32 bits, 4 bytes on those same systems) bytes from the file into this variable.

This will overwrite 4 bytes of the variable with the value read, but leave the other 4 uninitialized. Which 4 bytes it overwrites depends on the architecture (the least significant on Intel CPUs, the most significant on big-endian-configured ARMs), but the result will most likely be garbage either way, because 4 bytes were left uninitialized and could contain anything.

In your case, most likely they are the most significant bytes, and contain at least one non-zero bit, meaning that you then try to allocate far beyond 4GB of memory, which you don't have.

The solution is to make `state` a `std::uint32_t` (since you apparently expect the file to contain 4 bytes representing an unsigned integer; don't forget to include `<cstdint>`) and pass `sizeof(std::uint32_t)`, and in general make sure that for every `fread` and similar call where you pass in a pointer and a size, you make sure that the thing the pointer points to actually has exactly the size you pass along. Passing a `size_t*` and `sizeof(int)` does not fulfill these requirements on 64-bit systems, and since the size of C++'s basic types is not guaranteed, you generally don't want to use them for binary I/O at all.

Comment: i tried using std::uint32_t, but i am still getting the same bad_alloc() error. Please see the state value after fread call  -"3435973238" (This is with size_t). With std::uint32 it comes to higher then this. Actually my problem was that my "state" variable comes uninitialized from fread() function.

Answer (score 1):

There are a various things which you could improve in your C++ code, but there are a number of reasons, why you end up with this behaviour:

First, the variable `state` is of type `size_t`, but your code attempts to initialize its value using `fread(&state, sizeof(int), 1, pFile);`. Now, if `sizeof(state) != sizeof(int)` then you have undefined behaviour. If `sizeof(state) < sizeof(int)`, then the `fread` statement usually overwrites some arbitrary memory after the storage for variable `state`. This leads to undefined behaviour (e.g. `state` might have some random large value, and allocation fails).

Second, if `sizeof(state) > sizeof(int)`, then `state` is only partially initialized and its actual value depends on both the initialized (by `fread`) and the uninitialized bits. So its value can be a large number and allocation may fail.

Third, the if `sizeof(state) == sizeof(int)` then it just might be that the the value read is too large, and allocation simply fails because you run out of memory.

Fourth, the value you read from the file might have some different encoding or endianness. For example, if value was written to the file in big-endian format, but is `fread` on a little-endian CPU, might cause the bytes to be incorrectly swapped. You might need to swap the bytes before using the value read.

I suggest you instead use some fixed-width integer type from `<cstdint>` (or `<stdint.h>` for pre-C++11), such as `std::uint64_t` for variable `state`, read the value using `fread(&state, sizeof(state), 1, pFile);`, and then byte-swap `state` if the endianness of your CPU doesn't match the endianness of the value stored in the file.

Answer (score 0):

You should decide what the maximum number of characters you are willing to allocate is and error out if `state` is greater than that. Almost certainly, it is.